# Regular expression to grab Red Hat release version

Tags: regex, centos

Running command `uname -r` gives us:

```
3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
```

I need to extract "el7". I'm not that great with regexp and could use a helping hand. If you could, explain what is going on in the solution.

Thank you

Comment: So if the format for this will always look relatively like that, and el is the only form that will outlie the first point then. https://regex101.com/r/kN6iA9/1. It is however extremely doubtful that it will always be like that. Full command to extract that would be `uname -r | grep -P '[el]{2}[0-9]'` .

Comment: I am not familiar with Red Hat release versions. If you could show some more, it would be easier to identify a pattern. For example: is it *always* 3 dot-separated blocks of digits, a hyphen, 3 more dot-separated blocks of digits, a dot, the string you want, dot, another string? Or can there be variations, like: 4 blocks of digits instead of 3, some more letters in between, and so on? How do *you* understand it's `el7`? Because of what is before it, because of what is after it...?

Comment: just `uname -r | grep -o 'el[0-9][0-9]*'` the second 0-9 is optionnal to plan for future Redhat enterprise linux above 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH you can use this regex:

```
s='3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64'
[[ $s =~ ([^.]+)\.[^.]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
el7
```

Or without regex using awk:

```
uname -r | awk -F '.' '{print $(NF-1)}'
el7
```

Comment: Perfect. Awk is probably best in this use case. Thank you.